# How to control caption placement for figures in KnitR?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Is there a way to specify the placement of captions for figures generated by R using KnitR? I'm hoping that there's something functionally equivalent to `xtable()`'s `caption.placement` option.

A minimal working example is provided below.

```
\documentclass[12pt, english, oneside]{amsart}
\begin{document}

The caption for Figure \ref{fig:plot} is placed below the figure. Could we place it above, instead?
<<plot, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Default caption placement is below the figure.">>=
plot(x=0, y=0)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you give a reproducible example? you ask about figures but you give an example of tables..

Comment: I added a MWE. Sorry I didn't provide it initially.

Comment: there are LaTeX solutions, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22751/how-to-force-table-caption-on-top and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/table-captions-are-always-placed-below it seems you can use the `floatrow` package; I think the convention is to put figure captions below figures, so this may not be a convincing feature request to me

Comment: Okay, I can deal with that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

This would likely be best to deal with in the latex style for all figures, but you can customize figures with hooks.  The `fig.env` chunk option controls the environment the block is inserted into.  You could always make your own version of `figure` with your own formatting.